# Bar chart not functioning the way I would want it

Tags: java

I was hoping if you can help me with this coding. I'm attempting to create a bar chart but it doesn't seem to be going my. I m trying to make the output below but when I run it I get `[Red, Yellow, Blue](0)` repeating. I feel like I'm close to solving this. If someone can push me in the right direction in what I can do it would be appreciated greatly.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //These arrays are not to be modified and should only use these 2 arrays.
        short[] points ={1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,1,5};
        String[] teams ={"Red","Yellow","Blue","Blue","Blue","Red","Yellow","Red","Yellow","Red","Blue","Blue"};
        Set<String> uniqueTeams = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(teams));
        Barchart(points, teams, uniqueTeams);
    }

    public static void Barchart(short[] points, String[] teams, Set<String> uniqueTeams){
        byte count=0;
        for(int index=0; index < points.length; index++){
            if(teams.equals(uniqueTeams)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        for(int index=0; index < points.length; index++){
            System.out.println(uniqueTeams + "("+ count + ")");
        }

    }
}

//Output should look like this:
//
//Red(7): *******
//
//Yellow(6): ******
//
//Blue(9): *********
```

I have a idea of how to do it another way but I don't know how. If someone can answer this question below.
How would I be able to get or create a new array without having doubles of what I do in the teams array? So the array would look like String[] uniqueTeams = {"Red, "Yellow", "Blue"}; but not initialize or declare it but create a way to make the program create itself if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out `uniqueTeams` directly. `uniqueTeams` is of type `Set`. What you should be doing is cycling through each of the items inside the set, and printing out the stars next to them.

**The OOP Approach**

If it were me, I would not have everything in separate data structures, it makes for very messy code. Why not create a `Bar` object, that will contain the value and the name. Then you simply need to cycle through a collection of type `Bar` and call the `toString()` method`, which you will override.

**While I'm here**

I figure I might as well give you a step by step with the OOP approach. With Object Oriented Programming, we want to contain similar data in objects. For example, the name and value of a bar is a great object to make; all the data relates to the class.

```
class Bar
{
private int count;
private String name;
    // Some values here to store the count and the name of the bar.

public Bar(String name, int count)
{
            // Assign those values in the constructor.
    this.name = name;
    this.count = count;
}
// Override the Object toString() method, and replace it with our code:
public String toString()
{
    String stars = "";
    for(int x = 0; x < count; x++)
    {
        stars += "*";
    }
            // Create the stars string, and append it to the name and count.
    return name + ":" + count + " | " + stars;
}
}
```

Now to access this code is much, much simpler than your solution. First, we create an `ArrayList`, something like `barChart` to store all the values, and we parameterize it to type `Bar`:

```
  ArrayList<Bar> barChart = new ArrayList<Bar>();
```

Then we can add some test cases in:

```
  barChart.add(new Bar("Red", 10));
  barChart.add(new Bar("Blue", 20));
  barChart.add(new Bar("Green", 12));
```

Now, because you have overridden the `toString` method, you can now simply pass the objects to a `System.out.println()` function. Something like:

```
  for(Bar b : barChart) { 
     System.out.println(b);  
  }
```

*Output*

Red:10 | ********* 
  Blue:20 | ******************** 
  Green:12 | ************

Comment: Wow, that makes great sense, thank you so much for that. But one of the requirements to do this is not to do it as a OOP. Only have one class with several methods.

Comment: My lord that's horrific, but not the end of the world :P. You simply need to read the first section of my code; you're printing out the entire collection, when you only want to print out each item in the collection.

Comment: Yes I know its hell, I've been doing this darn thing for about 4 days straight only completing 2/3's and this is the last hurdle.